# How to split one StringList into Two string lists in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, listbox, split

I'm trying to split a StringList content into multiple parts (in Delphi)...
Sounds easy but I'm stupidly blocked :o

For example, the StringList contains 1001 lines and I would like to split the content into 2 StringLists. So, one will have 500 lines, and the other one will have 501 lines.
No matter if the first have 501 and the second 500, or vice versa.

If someone can push me on the right way...
Thanks in advance !

Beny

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
for I := SL1.Count - 1 downto (SL1.Count div 2) do
begin
  SL2.Insert(0, SL1[I]);
  SL1.Delete(I);
end;
```

Comment: +1. I wrote this at first, but it requires all of the strings put into the second stringlist to be shifted each time you insert. I changed mine to not require that by using two separate loops. Depending on the size of the original stringlist, they're probably about the same performance - on bigger lists, I think mine is slightly faster, since it doesn't have to reallocate and move every time, but just has the allocation. :)

Comment: Just perfect ! Now I'll try split in 3 parts.

Comment: Does the order of the strings in SL2 matter? If not, you can make this a bit faster by using .Add instead of .Insert.

Comment: @KenWhite, I totally agree that with large lists your code is much faster.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it manually pretty easily:

```
var
  i: Integer;
  MidIndex, HighIndex: Integer;
begin
  MidIndex := SLOne.Count div 2;   // Center of first list's items
  HighIndex := SLOne.Count - 1;    // End of  first list

  // Copy from center to end of first list, keeping order
  // of items intact
  for i := MidIndex to HighIndex do
    SLTwo.Append(SLOne[i]);

  // Go back and remove the ones you just put into the second
  // list. Go backward to prevent going past the end.
  for i := HighIndex downto MidIndex  do
    SLOne.Delete(i);
end;
```

Comment: +1 This is O(N) rather than Kobik's O(N^2). One minor quibble. is that the code would be more readable with some explanatory local vars for the loop bounds. And that would also make it clearer that the two loops covered the same ranges.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, I don't see how my code is `O(N^2)`. `Insert` does not shifts `O(N)` elements. It sets a new capacity same as `Add`, and Moves (Shifts) the entire block in Memory. Please explain.

Comment: @kobik The shifts themselves will be O(N).

Comment: The obvious downside with my code is with the memory blocks being shifted. with very large lists, it is much better to use Kens code.